# How to align elements on the inside edge of a <div> tag?

Tags: css, html

How do I align an element on the inside edge of a  tag? That is, so that it works like absolute positioning but only inside the  tag.
I think a way it would work is if it were possible to force the element to think the  tag was the actual page, but I don't know if this is possible/ideal.

EDIT:
http://www.flickr.com/photos/chustar/3736370208/
here's a mockup of what i mean

Comment: Not sure I quite understand. Could you provide a mock up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need to do here is make the container element `position:relative;` and then make the "positioned" elements `position:absolute;`

```
.container {
  position:relative;
}

.child1 {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}

.child2 {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
}

<div class="container">
  <div class="child1">Top left element</div>
  <div class="child2">Bottom right element</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

When you set the container element (a `<div>` for example) to "position: relative", and you set the inner element to "position: absolute", the inner element is positioned relative to the outer one, not the page.